# Django not parsing query string if the question mark is escaped

Tags: django, query-string, django-urls

Shouldn't Django be able to parse an escaped query string like so:

```
localhost:8000/sampleurl/myurl%3Fkey=value
```

like it was this:

```
localhost:8000/sampleurl/myrurl?key=value
```

Instead I'm getting a 404. This is the URL:

```
url(r'^sampleurl/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    ...
```

I was able to partially solve it by setting the url like so:

```
url(r'^sampleurl(?P<slug>[-\w]+)(.*?)$',
    ...
```

But doesn't work 100% and it seems unnecessary.

Comment: no, the purpose of escaping a question mark is so that you don't use it as the query string delimiter.

Comment: @bryan60 Some clients request it like that (ie, imagine an app requesting the url like the), is there a setting on Django (middleware) or apache, or will I need to solve that at a view level?

Comment: clients sending requests like that are breaking http. you could probably write a middlewear but you should just force your clients to follow http